# validar si se insertó un archivo en un input tipo file

Tags: jsp, fileupload, null

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y necesito saber si el input de tipo file tiene algo para insertarlo en la BD, estuve intentando validando si era diferente de nulo, pero aunque no le ponga ningun archivo entra como si fuera diferente de nulo.

```
iPart part = request.getPart("aFoto");
        if (part != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
            c.setFoto(inputStream);
        }
```

Comment: El input que tiene el name "aFoto" es de tipo file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazlo desde el html/jsp y pon lo siguiente:

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" name="texto" accept="application/pdf,image/jpg" required/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

El accept es para que acepte las extensiones de un tipo de archivo o varios como en este caso que los separas por **,**

Ah, y el **required** es para que el cliente no pueda dejar ese campo vacío.

Comment: No creo que sea la respuesta, ocupo que el input sea de tipo file

Comment: Fijate así, ahí la modifiqué

Comment: Está bien, pero yo diría que técnicamente es la mitad de la respuesta, porque se seguiría sin validar nulos en el backend; `inputStream.available();` nos diría en el backend si realmente hay contenido o no.

Comment: Ruslan López, muchas gracias, era lo que esperaba :)

Answer (score 0):

Para todos con esta duda, esta es la respuesta...

```
            Part part = request.getPart("aFoto");

            InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();

            if (inputStream.available() != 0) {
                c.setFoto(inputStream);
            }
```

Comment: Por favor edita y considera explicar para que el resto de personas que consulten sepan que modificaste o agregaste